Some syntax confusion in Python related to string literals
I am learning to manipulate data using Python. While I was learning with some course online, I found this piece of code having string literals.
w = 200                         
b = 100    
x_i = 1.2
cost_1200sqft = w * x_i + b    
print(f"${cost_1200sqft:.0f} thousand dollars")

I don't know what :.0f means, can I please have some help?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec
